# How to create a vector of strings from a vector of string_view without iteration?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following vector:

```
std::vector<std::string_view> const keys{"A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "C1"};
```

I want to create a vector of `std::string` out of it without iterating over it.

Comment: Someone is going to have to iterate over that vector, creating strings from the string_view.

Comment: You can't accomplish this without iteration. But if you don't want to iterate manually, then use an algorithm like `std::for_each()` or `std::transform()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::string> v(keys.begin(), keys.end());
```

should do it. Of course, there's iteration hidden inside that constructor.

Comment: Yeah. This is what I was looking for.